# railstutorial.org gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/tmux/client.rb:12:in `version': undefined method

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm following the Ruby on Rails tutorial at RailsTutorial.org and am on section 3.3.1 (/book/static_pages#cha-static_pages) for running 'rails test' for the first time. I'm using the Cloud9 IDE per the recommendation and as far as I can tell I have followed the script exactly. Everything has matched up to this point.

I have also done some searches on the error and come up with comments about something called tmux but I'm not sufficiently experienced enough in Ruby on Rails or Cloud9 to be sure of what I'm doing. Someone also recommended doing 'bundle exec rake test' as an alternative but I get the same error:

```
2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/tmux/client.rb:12:in 'version': undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/tmux.rb:69:in '_check_available'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/base.rb:59:in 'initialize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:100:in 'new'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:100:in '_add'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:62:in 'block (2 levels) in detect'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:60:in 'each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:60:in 'detect'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:60:in 'block in detect'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:59:in 'each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:59:in 'detect'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:180:in '_detect_or_add_notifiers'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:198:in '_activate'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:87:in 'initialize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:42:in 'new'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/notiffany-0.1.1/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:42:in 'connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/notifier.rb:11:in 'connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/notifier.rb:31:in 'notify'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/guard-compat-1.2.1/lib/guard/compat/plugin.rb:113:in 'notify'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/guard/minitest/notifier.rb:31:in 'notify'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/guard/minitest/reporter.rb:10:in 'report'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:791:in 'each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:791:in 'report'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:141:in 'run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:63:in 'block in autorun'
```

I don't see anything called notiffany in the Gemfile, but I've found it's related to Guard. Since I'm using the specific version indicated by the tutorial, I'm not sure if looking for a newer version there is the fix.

It is possible I'm just not searching for the right keywords, so I apologize if this has been answered before. Any help is appreciated.

-Jay

Comment: This was actually already covered in the tutorial, which has a note for C9 users: "In particular, the default Gemfile might not work on the cloud IDE, so follow the instructions at the top of the reference Guardfile if you’re using Cloud9." The solution posted here is better, though, so I've updated the tutorial accordingly.

Comment: @mhartl That line only appears right at the bottom in the Advanced testing section. While going through the tutorial for the very first time, nothing is mentioned at all. Regardless, the error has nothing to do with the Guardfile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo yum install -y tmux
```

As suggested on [this](http://yskoht.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/12/26/140450) Japanese site.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. I tried following your link but Malwarebytes threw an exception. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Fixed aws cloud9 error while working on rails tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-guard